# Issue with Configuration Change table in Log analytics

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics, change-tracking

I am unable to see any data in configuration change table in my automation account in azure. Although the change tracking is enabled for the VM's it still doesnt push any data to the table in log analytics. Can someone help me with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to double check whether you are querying the 'ConfigurationChange' table in the correct Log Analytics workspace or not.

If you have already checked it and if you are querying in the correct Log Analytics workspace then I suggest you to check whether your agents' operating system holds good with the supported operating system versions as explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/change-tracking#supported-windows-operating-systems).

If that is also not an issue then I suggest you to diagnose the issue based on output comment that you are seeing when you query 'ConfigurationChange' table. Is that '0 records matched for the selected time range' or 'Failed to resolve table or column or scalar expression named' or something else!?

If still issue persists then I suggest you to file a support ticket (using [these](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request) steps) with Azure support team who would troubleshoot / diagnose the issue by accessing your setup and the related backend debug logs that are based on kusto explorer, etc.

Hope this information helps! Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I found out that there is a new preview feature in Azure called Scope Configuration under Workspace Data sources tab in which it creates a group of the servers for which change tracking is enabled by default and it has to be succeded. I was facing this issue because the group went into intialiazing state instead of success. I have deleted the group and my logs were flowing to the configuration change table.

Comment: Great! Thanks for sharing!